# Does exists Eclipse plugin for log files?

Tags: eclipse, text, editor, logging

I have check very long logs after each start of Tomcat (from Eclipse).
Does exist a plugin or editor that I can use inside Eclipse? At least it must have colored for errors, debug and info messages.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using Log4j:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j

It works great with eclipse and has the color scheme built in. It's highly customizable, takes some time to figure out but it's worth it.

Comment: I need plugin but not separate application.

Comment: I don't understand what you need. Log4j is a plugin not a seperate application.

Answer (score 1):

The code to do this is rather simple, aside from syntax coloring.  Just start a plugin project, add dependancies for `org.eclipse.ui.console` and do something like this:

```
public void log() {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path of log file"));

    String line = null;
    while (br.nextLine ) {
        line = br.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        else {
            MessageConsole console = findConsole("tomcat log");
            MessageConsoleStream stream = console.newMessageStream();
            stream.println(message);
        }
    }
}

private MessageConsole findConsole(String name) {
    ConsolePlugin plugin = ConsolePlugin.getDefault();
    IConsoleManager conMan = plugin.getConsoleManager();
    IConsole[] existing = conMan.getConsoles();
    for (IConsole element : existing)
        if (name.equals(element.getName()))
            return (MessageConsole) element;
    // no console found, so create a new one
    MessageConsole myConsole = new MessageConsole(name, null);
    conMan.addConsoles(new IConsole[] { myConsole });
    return myConsole;
}
```

Comment: I asked ready to use plugin, but not advice to write it myself.